# Castor compilation problem

Tags: java, compilation, classpath, castor

I got "cannot access org.exolab.castor.core.exceptions.CastorException" from the compiler when I try to use Marshal and unmarshal. I used Castor 1.3

```
    try {

        Writer writer = new FileWriter("out.xml");
        Marshaller.marshal(person, writer);
        Reader reader = new FileReader("out.xml");
        metaType = (Person) Unmarshaller.unmarshal(Person.class, reader);

    }catch (MarshalException e) {
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
    }
```

Comment: This is a compilation error.  sorry not exception problem. I have no error shown on the code just when compile i hit the error. I had already import thejar file

Comment: Why did you edit your question with a new problem instead of posting a new one? Now the answers doesn't make any sense anymore. Please rollback the edit, accept the answer which helped in solving the problem and post a new question. I am not going to edit my answer here to reflect your entirely changed question/problem.

Comment: No answer that helped in solving the problem. and I will post a new question thanks.

Comment: Your earlier problem was a compilation error. You apparently fixed that, because otherwise you wouldn't be able to get this **new** problem (which is just a step further). Those problems are **unrelated** to each other. Please post each *independent* problem in **its own** topic/question. I am going to rollback your edit now.

Comment: Thanks to help me rollback the problem, but there are no answer can solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this is **not** an *exception*, this is a *compilation error*. The code isn't even able to become a runnable `.class` file. That's a huge difference. In the future you should try to be more explicit about that.

This compilation error actually means that the mentioned class is missing in the classpath during compiletime. If you're compiling using `javac`, then you need to add the full path to the Castor JAR file which includes the mentioned class to the `-cp` (classpath) argument. Something like this:

```
javac -cp .;c:/path/to/Castor.jar com/example/YourClass.java
```

*That was a Windows Example; in Unix/Linux and clones you need `:` as path separator. Individual paths with spaces inside should be enclosed by quotes.*

Comment: i run the file from jdeveloper, how do i add in the path?

Comment: Check the *Libraries* section in the project properties.